# oracle spatial sdo_on function returns no rows

Tags: oracle, geometry, spatial

Here is my sample table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.loc, t.x, t.y,t.id vertex_num
FROM my_test p, TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(p.geom))t
where p.id in (23, 24);

    id    loc       x   y  vetex_num
--------------------------------
    23  RECTANGLE   1   10  1
    23  RECTANGLE   15  20  2
    24  LINE        1   10  1
    24  LINE        15  10  2
```

It seems the boundaries of the LINE interacts with the boundary of RECTANGLE which should return TRUE for SDO_ON function,

```
SELECT  A.loc , b.loc
FROM my_test A, my_test b
WHERE SDO_ON(A.geom, B.geom) = 'TRUE';
```

but it results none , Thought it shows result for  ANYINTERACT. I've tried with SDO_RELATE with 'mask= on' parameter, but no rows returned.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found at last!!

The problem is with the SRID, (my indexed and tabular SRID was 8307)
I've change the SRID whcih supports the wkt as PROJECTED cordinates.
eg. 32774, 90112,
I used 32774 and queried the same above and now the i got result like expected:

```
LOC  LOC_1
----------
LINE RECT
```

But I still do not understand  why does it not working with srid 8307.